# 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'DisplayEquation'

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I have written code which plot graph. Now I need to add trendline to that graph. When i tried it. It gives below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmp655972\Desktop\Python\test_1.py", line 87, in <module>
    trend.DisplayEquation = True
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'DisplayEquation'
```

Code:

```
worksheets = workbook.Sheets(1) chart= worksheets.Shapes.AddChart(72) print (chart)      
worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.HasTitle = True                                                                                           worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Testing Samples" 
trend =worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines().Add
trend.DisplayEquation = True
```

Comment: Code is as below :                                            worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.HasTitle = True
worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Testing Samples"
trend = worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines().Add
trend.DisplayEquation = True

Comment: you can use the edit-button to edit your post, and to put in your code.

Comment: Code: 
worksheets = workbook.Sheets(1)
chart= worksheets.Shapes.AddChart(72)
print (chart)
worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.HasTitle = True
worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Testing Samples"
trend = worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines().Add
trend.DisplayEquation = True

Comment: Is anybody knows the answer.....???

Comment: Why did you ignore what usethedeathstar said? **Edit your question**, and **paste that code there** so that we can read it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : HI.....I edited but it didn't work

Comment: Just a guess - should `Add` be invoked?  You can do this by placing `()` after it.

Comment: @iCodez:It is resolved by placing () after Add. How should we know that it Add invoked or not?

Comment: Hey, that fixed it?  Huh, I should have made that an answer then.  I just thought it was strange `Add`, which is an instancemethod, wasn't invoked.  In Python, you invoke (call) methods by placing `()` after them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make my comment an answer because it solved the problem.  That way, it can help any future visitors to this page.

You need to invoke `Add` by placing `()` after it:

```
trend =worksheets.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines().Add()
#                                                                     here--^
```

Now, `trend` points to what it should, namely the return value of the `Add` method.

Comment: @Jay - That's great!  I'm happy too because I just took a shot in the dark (when I wrote the comment, I was busy with something else and didn't have time to read your post in detail).  However, if my answer solved your problem, then you should accept it (click the tick) to let people know it worked.

Comment: @iCodez-Now I plot chart. I need to copy that chart into powerpoint. How can i do it?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there because I do not use powerpoint.  Why not ask a new question?